# Avoid multiple modal when the request timeout

Tags: bug, ios-app

When the connection is really slow, everytime a request time out a got multiple error modal. At least 2, but sometimes 3. Isn't possible to know if a modal allready show up and avoid multiple modal?

[image: time out]

Comment: We should definitely only show one per request.  What screen is this, what were you doing?

Comment: I was just refreshing the main "Feed" before trying to refresh the "stackoverflow" feed. But I was in the subway, with a very low connection, nearly nothing actually.

Comment: That's odd.  I'm trying to reproduce.  The feed doesn't have a "Retry" alert and I can't get the question list to trigger a new alert without a new request.  Is it possible that the first request is something like "The request timed out." followed by an immediate "The Internet connection appears to be offline."?  If there's not connection and retry immediately fails, a new alert would appear.

Comment: Well, I'll give another try tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: I tried yesterday and got 2 alert, like you said. I guess that I've tried to load several page (like so + mso + global feed) and then got 3 alert for each request. Which seems to be normal.